# Quantile regression standard error and the OLS standard error

Tags: standard-error, quantile-regression

I was asked by a non-statistician what is the driving factor for the standard error estimates of the parameters. Here are my thoughts:

1. From asymptotic theory, both OLS standard error and Quantile regression standard error depends on the error/residual distribution. The OLS standard error mainly depends on the variance of the error distribution, while the quantile regression depends on the density at the $\tau$th quantile.
2. More often the iid assumption does not hold for the residuals, so bootstrap methods are used. There is no explicit formular to explain what should be driving the standard error estimation in this case. But it should perform similar to the iid case when there are lots of observations.

Anyone has a more right, clear and intuitive explanation?